# Incorrect boolean result when finding square root of n in another array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function for a kata that takes two arrays and compares the values in `array2` to `array1` to check if the square root of the number in `array2` exists in `array1`.

I hope that makes sense.

the issue I have is that the automated test that checks the challenge if flagging the the below combination as being false whereas my code evaluates it to true.

Array1: `[ 2, 2, 3 ]`
Array2: `[ 4, 4, 9 ]`

From what I can see, this combination should evaluate to true. 2 being the square root of 4 and 3 being the square root of 9.

The code works fine in all other instances. Only the above input if failing the tests.

Am I missing something here either in the math or in my solution?

```js
function comp(array1, array2) {

  if (!Array.isArray(array1) || !Array.isArray(array2)) {
    return false;
  }

  let result = true;
  for (let n of array2) {
    if (array1.includes(Math.sqrt(n))) {
      continue;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const array1 = [2, 2, 3];
const array2 = [4, 4, 9];

console.log(comp(array1, array2));
```

Comment: Hi @Amy for of doesn't loop the indices, for in does

Comment: Woops!  You're right!  I typed the wrong thing (`in`) in my console!  So sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Its better if you turn array1 into a set inside of your function, this will prevent walking an array every iteration and be instant access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the actual issue was that I was looking at the wrong arrays! The code was not handling arrays like so where each items in array2 needed a unique square root in array1. Code below corrected this.

Array1: `[2, 6, 3]`

Array2: `[4, 4, 9]`

```
function comp(array1, array2){

  if ( !Array.isArray(array1) || !Array.isArray(array2) ) { return false;}

  let result = true;
  array1.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
  array2.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if ( array1[i] === Math.sqrt(array2[i]) ) {
      continue;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code, thus avoiding potential bugs:

```
function comp(array1, array2) {
  if (!Array.isArray(array1) || !Array.isArray(array2)) {
    return false;
  }
  return array2.some(x => array1.includes(Math.sqrt(x)))
}

const array1 = [2, 2, 3];
const array2 = [4, 4, 9];

console.log(comp(array1, array2));
```